# IOS storyboard not able to add storyboard in compile sources

Tags: ios, xcode6, storyboard

In my xcode i am not able to add `main.storyboard`. Today i faced the issue related to storyboard. when i call the storyboard in appdelegate.m file .xcode gives error at runtime.

> reason: 'Could not find a storyboard named 'Main.storyboard' in bundle

I seen sever threads related to this issue and all said add storyboard in `compile sources` and `copybundle sources`. i have added storyboard in both the place but still i run the project again storyboard is removed and i got runtime error. i tried with multiple time. even storyboard is not located in `compile sources` list, so we have to choose option `add other`. but still got this error. how can i solve this issue? or i am missing something in this process?

[image: Story Board issue]

Comment: Do you have the storyboard added to each target? Also can you show the code for how you are accessing your storyboard in your AppDelegate.

Comment: @egarlock : where i have to set target for  storyboard? and i have declare storyboards object in `appdelegate.h` and declare it in this way in appdelegate.m file. `    _storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main.storyboard" bundle:nil];
`